# Canadian immigration: Admissibility process mystery

Tags: canada, immigration, admissibility

This is a question I've asked at various Q&A sites and forums to no avail. Of course I also asked my own consultant, and several other lawyers and advisors, but none had the answer. I don't have high hopes, but who knows, so here we go.

I'm an asylum claimant in Canada. I've presented my asylum application in January 2018. A short time later I was arrested and detained. I was informed that I'm going to have to pass an admissibility hearing to be allowed to carry on with my asylum claim. The reason is possible serious criminality.

*(Before you'd assume I'm some fugitive criminal who naively thought Canada will protect me from lawful consequences if I cry a little bit: no, I'm not. I was harassed by the authorities for years in my home country on political grounds, and I was charged with various criminal offences. I'm carrying several thousand pages of evidence to this unlawful and unfair treatment, all properly translated and prepared for presentation. The question is not whether my claim may be well-founded or not.)*

I was released in March 2018 on a quite low bail. I was mandated to report once a month personally at the local CBSA office. I've also been told that a disclosure is going to be prepared and sent to me, with CBSA's statements for the forthcoming admissibility hearing.

*I'm fully aware of the purpose, nature and legal regulations of the admissibility process. That's not what the question is about. Please read on.*

In September 2018 I got a text message from Purolator about a package. I checked it online, and I found that it was sent to an address entirely unknown to me. It was in Sherborough, Toronto while I was living in Montreal, with full consent and knowledge of CBSA of course. There's no way to change the delivery address, so I just watched as it expired and went back to them. I thought they'll realize their mistake and resend it to my actual address. But that never happened.

In February 2019 when I went to report, I was asked to confirm my address on a form. I did so. Nothing happened.

In November 2019 an agent of SCIS - the Canadian federal intelligence service - visited my bondsperson and asked if he knows where I am. He told her that I'm still residing at the same address they have on file, and I'm reporting exactly as I was obliged.

Nothing happened ever since. I've been released more than two years ago. I got a work permit and even worked in a job requiring government security clearance. Why do you think CBSA isn't sending anything?

It's been suggested they're overworked. That may be, but they can't be so busy that they can't resend an already prepared document. Some said it's because of COVID-19. No, it's not, there was no COVID until March 2020. Maybe they don't think I'm a safety concern any more. Then why don't they just let me carry on with my life? Really nobody has any idea. Do you?

Comment: Have you tried asking your local federal legislator's office to look into this? I don't know about Canada specifically, but MPs in the UK and representatives and senators in the US have offices that follow up with the executive on problems faced by their constituents. As an asylum seeker (who cannot vote), you're obviously in a weaker position than a citizen would be, but it's certainly worth a try.

Comment: I don't think that'd work. MPs hardly even read the letters they receive, and you can't blame them - just imagine how much they get every day. Even if he somehow got it and decided to investigate, it'd be just one of his many problems. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Don't write, call.  They have phone lines for these cases.  And staff members to do the legwork.  The MP doesn't actually handle the matter at all in most cases.  My father was unable to get the US INS to look up his father's naturalization records, but he called our representative's office and they got it done for him. I've heard similar stories in the UK.  You really should try it.  It's a small investment of your time considering the gravity of the matter at hand and considering the stupidity of the mistake CBSA seems to have made.

Comment: You're right, it costs nothing to try. Though it may still amount to nothing. Thanks!